# How to split list of strings into sublists where len("".join(sublist)) <= N?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm given a list of strings and a length limit `N`.  I have to write a function to accumulate consecutive strings in the list until the next string would exceed the `N` limit.  I have to return a list of lists, where each list is the largest consecutive substring not to exceed `N` characters total.
See the test case below for an example.  Also, if any single string in the list is longer than `N`, I have to print a useful message and return.

```
def break_lst(lst, size):
    def len_lst(l):
        return len("".join(l))

    result = []
    sublst = []

    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        sublst.append(v)
        ls = len_lst(sublst)

        if ls == size:
            result.append(sublst)
            sublst = []
        elif ls > size:
            prev_sublst = sublst[:-1]
            if not prev_sublst or len_lst(prev_sublst) > size:
                raise Exception("Error: use a bigger size than " + str(size))
            else:
                result.append(prev_sublst)
                sublst = []

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = ["1", "22", "333", "4444", "55555", "666666", "7777777", "88888888"]

    for i in range(17):
        try:
            print(i, break_lst(lst, size=i))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

The above code it's not only ugly but also buggy, it's giving me this output:

```
Error: use a bigger size than 0
Error: use a bigger size than 1
Error: use a bigger size than 2
Error: use a bigger size than 3
Error: use a bigger size than 4
Error: use a bigger size than 5
Error: use a bigger size than 6
Error: use a bigger size than 7
8 [['1', '22', '333'], ['55555'], ['7777777']]
9 [['1', '22', '333'], ['55555'], ['7777777']]
10 [['1', '22', '333', '4444'], ['55555'], ['7777777']]
11 [['1', '22', '333', '4444'], ['666666']]
12 [['1', '22', '333', '4444'], ['666666']]
13 [['1', '22', '333', '4444'], ['666666', '7777777']]
14 [['1', '22', '333', '4444'], ['666666', '7777777']]
15 [['1', '22', '333', '4444', '55555'], ['666666', '7777777']]
16 [['1', '22', '333', '4444', '55555']]
```

When the expected output should be:

```
Error: use a bigger size than 0
Error: use a bigger size than 1
Error: use a bigger size than 2
Error: use a bigger size than 3
Error: use a bigger size than 4
Error: use a bigger size than 5
Error: use a bigger size than 6
Error: use a bigger size than 7
8 [['1', '22', '333'], ['4444'], ['55555'], ['666666'], ['7777777'], ['88888888']]
9 [['1', '22', '333'], ['4444', '55555'], ['666666'], ['7777777'], ['88888888']]
10 [['1', '22', '333', '4444'], ['55555'], ['666666'], ['7777777'], ['88888888']]
11 [['1', '22', '333', '4444'], ['55555', '666666'], ['7777777'], ['88888888']]
12 [['1', '22', '333', '4444'], ['55555', '666666'], ['7777777'], ['88888888']]
13 [['1', '22', '333', '4444'], ['55555', '666666'], ['7777777'], ['88888888']]
14 [['1', '22', '333', '4444'], ['55555', '666666'], ['7777777'], ['88888888']]
15 [['1', '22', '333', '4444', '55555'], ['666666', '7777777'], ['88888888']]
16 [['1', '22', '333', '4444', '55555'], ['666666', '7777777'], ['88888888']]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please revert the post to the original question; the answer no longer matches.  Your new question should be posted as exactly that: a new question.  
 
Also, improvement of working code belongs in CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: @Prune Yeah, sure, btw... why did someone downvote this question? As far as I understand it follows SO rules, even if it's newbie-level... :/

Comment: I don't know, since I"m not the down-voter.  However, I did consider down-voting because of not describing the problem at hand.  I wrote up a description, which I hope fixes that problem.

Comment: @Prune Thanks for the nice editing, now the problem has become much clearer indeed. Next time I'll consider writing the problem description instead just pasting the code. I didn't do so with the original question because I assumed just providing the broken code/output/expected_output everybody would understand it... but it seems I was wrong :)

Comment: Perhaps.  When you *know* your code is ugly, don't assume that people will read it to reverse-engineer the problem, especially when the code doesn't properly solve the problem.  We all keep improving ... that's what the site is about.  I'm no exception.

Comment: As an additional note, the real-world case scenario for the exposed problem would be when you want to spawn subprocess on win32 that don't read from stdin and the length of args will be bigger than 32kb, look at `lpCmdLine` in [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx). The question can be applied to solve an interesting problem... So I'm quite curious why they've downvoted... IMHO when somebody downvotes they should be kind enough to explain the reasons of their downvotes, that way everybody would be able to improve their questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this section:

```
    elif ls > size:
        prev_sublst = sublst[:-1]
        if not prev_sublst or len_lst(prev_sublst) > size:
            raise Exception("Error: use a bigger size than " + str(size))
        else:
            result.append(prev_sublst)
            sublst = []
```

You've determined that the next list exceeds the given length.  You've properly backed up one element and recorded the maxed-out sublist.  However, you have *not* found a home for the `v` element that just blew your size limit.

For starters, try putting it into your new sublist:

```
        else:
            result.append(prev_sublst)
            sublst = [v]     # <=== the change is here.
```

Now, check your logic -- you'll want to validate this one-item list before you iterate to the next one.

One small comment on

```
for i, v in enumerate(lst):
```

Why did you go to the trouble of `enumerate` when you never use `i`?